# Evaluation of answers obtained from RAG architecture with RAGAS without OPENAI keys

Tags: openai-api, langchain, evaluation, large-language-model, llama

I have used Llama2 open source models for creating a chatbot for my personal documents using RAG architecture. I wish to evaluate the results obtained from RAG architecture with evaluation metrics , may be from RAGAS module. But it insists me to apply openAI API keys. Is there any alternative without using OpenAI API keys.

Any suggestions would be appreciated